# How can I implement an incremental suggestion for html textbox via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I would like to do...

Lets say I have a list of tags (ex; Animals, Alphabet, Buildings, Food).  I want to make it so that, as the user starts typing "A", they are then shown Alphabet (with the "lphabet" part highlighted and the cursor residing just after the "A").  As the user types, they are free to hit tab and accept the suggestion or they can continue typing in a custom value.

1. Is this possible?
2. What's the best way to implement this?

Currently, I am just replacing the value in the textbox with the matching value from the list (if found).  This doesn't work very well as it is difficult to use a custom value if it is close to an existing item in the list as the value is constantly overriden by the suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: you are basically talking about auto-complete functionality

Comment: Both [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/) have AutoComplete frameworks.  You can use these, or look at the code as an example.

Comment: Correct, autocomplete is exactly what I was looking for.  Had to pause for a second to see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

There is a JQuery plugin for Autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Awesome! Any reason to prefer this over the "datalist" option I found (also what Johnny suggested)?

Comment: Probably if you need to support IE9 and below..

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you are describing an autosuggest feature. You may find a lot of answers by searching the term.

If you have a known set of answers that is relatively short you may take advantage of the datalist as seen here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

If you have a very large or list that could depend on a database query you may be getting into a more complicated version. In this case I would look into JSON / AJAX Autosuggest.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Yeah, I did some searching on my own and ended up going for the datalist.  The list is on the smaller side so it makes sense here.

Comment: If you need to support older browsers and still wish to use the datalist then you may want to consider using https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv or equivalent. There may be other cases in which you find yourself wanting to use HTML5 features

Answer (score 1):

*Don't reinvent the web :)*

After stepping back to see the forest for the trees, I realized I could get essentially what I was looking for with the following...

```
<input list="tags" name="tag">
<datalist id="tags">
  <option value="Animal"></option>
  <option value="Alphabet"></option>
  <option value="Buildings"></option>
  <option value="Food"></option>
</datalist>
```